# Drupal White Screen of Death WHOD

Tags: drupal-7

I added a header for a view in Drupal 7 (PHP 5.6). I used PHP filter in the view header to add the PHP code for pytting a 'add content type' button on the view page. When I saved the view, the site gave me a blank screen. This happened to me quite a number of times. Now, since the site is not accessible I am not able to remove this code from the view header.
Is there any way to revert the white screen in drupal?

Comment: Please enable PHP `error_reporting`, consult your PHP error log, and post it in your question if you still need help.

Answer (score 0):

In **sites/default/settings.php** 
add code:

```
error_reporting(-1);
$conf['error_level'] = 2;
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```

Its enabled **error_reporting**.

Answer (score 0):

Open your index.php and paste the following code after

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```

Solution: 2
If your have your drupal database backup then drop your drupal database and create again the same database and import your previous backup database.It will work now.

Answer (score 0):

Try Disabling the view

```
$status = variable_get('views_defaults', array());
$status[$name] = TRUE;
variable_set('views_defaults', $status);
```